# Newer versions of docker have --cap-add, what CAP's can be added?

Tags: linux, docker, linux-capabilities

Newer versions of docker (I think 1.2 and later) have a `--cap-add` feature.

This gives fine grained control of feature capabilities without opening up everything with `--privileged=true`.

I've googled it, but can't find a list of capabilities and what they mean. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Funny enough... I googled this for an hour and couldn't find an answer. I ask the question here and found it in 2 secs.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html

When passing these to docker, you need to drop the CAP_ in the name.

i.e. to allow mounting inside a docker container

```
docker run --cap-add SYS_ADMIN ...
```

Comment: I believe it should be `--cap-add` with a hyphen.

Comment: And newer versions of docker allow you to have CAP_ on the front

Answer (score 17):

The following might be useful: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities

---

The following is extracted from the above page (3 Feb 2022):

---

By default, Docker has a default list of capabilities that are kept.
The following table lists the Linux capability options which are allowed by default and can be dropped.

| Capability Key | Capability Description |
| --- | --- |
| AUDIT_WRITE | Write records to kernel auditing log. |
| CHOWN | Make arbitrary changes to file UIDs and GIDs (see chown(2)). |
| DAC_OVERRIDE | Bypass file read, write, and execute permission checks. |
| FOWNER | Bypass permission checks on operations that normally require the file system UID of the process to match the UID of the file. |
| FSETID | Don’t clear set-user-ID and set-group-ID permission bits when a file is modified. |
| KILL | Bypass permission checks for sending signals. |
| MKNOD | Create special files using mknod(2). |
| NET_BIND_SERVICE | Bind a socket to internet domain privileged ports (port numbers less than 1024). |
| NET_RAW | Use RAW and PACKET sockets. |
| SETFCAP | Set file capabilities. |
| SETGID | Make arbitrary manipulations of process GIDs and supplementary GID list. |
| SETPCAP | Modify process capabilities. |
| SETUID | Make arbitrary manipulations of process UIDs. |
| SYS_CHROOT | Use chroot(2), change root directory. |

The next table shows the capabilities which are not granted by default and may be added.

| Capability Key | Capability Description |
| --- | --- |
| AUDIT_CONTROL | Enable and disable kernel auditing; change auditing filter rules; retrieve auditing status and filtering rules. |
| AUDIT_READ | Allow reading the audit log via multicast netlink socket. |
| BLOCK_SUSPEND | Allow preventing system suspends. |
| BPF | Allow creating BPF maps, loading BPF Type Format (BTF) data, retrieve JITed code of BPF programs, and more. |
| CHECKPOINT_RESTORE | Allow checkpoint/restore related operations. Introduced in kernel 5.9. |
| DAC_READ_SEARCH | Bypass file read permission checks and directory read and execute permission checks. |
| IPC_LOCK | Lock memory (mlock(2), mlockall(2), mmap(2), shmctl(2)). |
| IPC_OWNER | Bypass permission checks for operations on System V IPC objects. |
| LEASE | Establish leases on arbitrary files (see fcntl(2)). |
| LINUX_IMMUTABLE | Set the FS_APPEND_FL and FS_IMMUTABLE_FL i-node flags. |
| MAC_ADMIN | Allow MAC configuration or state changes. Implemented for the Smack LSM. |
| MAC_OVERRIDE | Override Mandatory Access Control (MAC). Implemented for the Smack Linux Security Module (LSM). |
| NET_ADMIN | Perform various network-related operations. |
| NET_BROADCAST | Make socket broadcasts, and listen to multicasts. |
| PERFMON | Allow system performance and observability privileged operations using perf_events, i915_perf and other kernel subsystems |
| [SYS_ADMIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58924511/why-is-granting-the-sys-admin-privilege-for-a-docker-container-bad) | Perform a range of system administration operations. |
| SYS_BOOT | Use reboot(2) and kexec_load(2), reboot and load a new kernel for later execution. |
| SYS_MODULE | Load and unload kernel modules. |
| SYS_NICE | Raise process nice value (nice(2), setpriority(2)) and change the nice value for arbitrary processes. |
| SYS_PACCT | Use acct(2), switch process accounting on or off. |
| SYS_PTRACE | Trace arbitrary processes using ptrace(2). |
| SYS_RAWIO | Perform I/O port operations (iopl(2) and ioperm(2)). |
| SYS_RESOURCE | Override resource Limits. |
| SYS_TIME | Set system clock (settimeofday(2), stime(2), adjtimex(2)); set real-time (hardware) clock. |
| SYS_TTY_CONFIG | Use vhangup(2); employ various privileged ioctl(2) operations on virtual terminals. |
| SYSLOG | Perform privileged syslog(2) operations. |
| WAKE_ALARM | Trigger something that will wake up the system. |