# Why is granting the SYS_ADMIN privilege for a Docker container "bad"?

Tags: docker, fuse

I am running into issues with security teams because engineering teams want to FUSE mount a filesystem in Docker, however, to do that, the "--cap-add SYS_ADMIN" flag must be set. Security is not allowing this flag.

I have found a lot of articles on the Internet regarding the "--cap-add SYS_ADMIN" flag during the Docker runtime as something to be cautious of because "SYS_ADMIN by itself grants quite a big part of the capabilities and it could potentially present more attack surface."

However, I cannot find anything which specifically states what these capabilities are and what "attack surfaces" they present?

What exactly does the SYS_ADMIN flag grant?

What is a practical security risk that is presented by setting this flag?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is basically root access to the host. From the capabilities man page:

> CAP_SYS_ADMIN
>                 Note: this capability is overloaded; see Notes to kernel
>                 developers, below.
>
> ```
>           * Perform a range of system administration operations
>             including: quotactl(2), mount(2), umount(2), pivot_root(2),
>             setdomainname(2);
>           * perform privileged syslog(2) operations (since Linux 2.6.37,
>             CAP_SYSLOG should be used to permit such operations);
>           * perform VM86_REQUEST_IRQ vm86(2) command;
>           * perform IPC_SET and IPC_RMID operations on arbitrary System
>             V IPC objects;
>           * override RLIMIT_NPROC resource limit;
>           * perform operations on trusted and security Extended
>             Attributes (see xattr(7));
>           * use lookup_dcookie(2);
>           * use ioprio_set(2) to assign IOPRIO_CLASS_RT and (before
>             Linux 2.6.25) IOPRIO_CLASS_IDLE I/O scheduling classes;
>           * forge PID when passing socket credentials via UNIX domain
>             sockets;
>           * exceed /proc/sys/fs/file-max, the system-wide limit on the
>             number of open files, in system calls that open files (e.g.,
>             accept(2), execve(2), open(2), pipe(2));
>           * employ CLONE_* flags that create new namespaces with
>             clone(2) and unshare(2) (but, since Linux 3.8, creating user
>             namespaces does not require any capability);
>           * call perf_event_open(2);
>           * access privileged perf event information;
>           * call setns(2) (requires CAP_SYS_ADMIN in the target
>             namespace);
>           * call fanotify_init(2);
>           * call bpf(2);
>           * perform privileged KEYCTL_CHOWN and KEYCTL_SETPERM keyctl(2)
>             operations;
>           * perform madvise(2) MADV_HWPOISON operation;
>           * employ the TIOCSTI ioctl(2) to insert characters into the
>             input queue of a terminal other than the caller's
>             controlling terminal;
>           * employ the obsolete nfsservctl(2) system call;
>           * employ the obsolete bdflush(2) system call;
>           * perform various privileged block-device ioctl(2) operations;
>           * perform various privileged filesystem ioctl(2) operations;
>           * perform privileged ioctl(2) operations on the /dev/random
>             device (see random(4));
>           * install a seccomp(2) filter without first having to set the
>             no_new_privs thread attribute;
>           * modify allow/deny rules for device control groups;
>           * employ the ptrace(2) PTRACE_SECCOMP_GET_FILTER operation to
>             dump tracee's seccomp filters;
>           * employ the ptrace(2) PTRACE_SETOPTIONS operation to suspend
>             the tracee's seccomp protections (i.e., the
>             PTRACE_O_SUSPEND_SECCOMP flag);
>           * perform administrative operations on many device drivers.
>           * Modify autogroup nice values by writing to
>             /proc/[pid]/autogroup (see sched(7)).
> ```

Comment: By "host" you mean the system that runs the container? Or are these privileges limited to the system inside the container? If a running docker container with `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` privilege has somehow access to the system that runs this container, can you give an example on how this privilege can be applied?

Comment: @goulashsoup the list of syscalls that get exposed is listed above. Not all of those syscalls are isolated to a namespace. No matter how many containers you run, there's only a single kernel processing those syscalls for the host and containers on the host. In particular, mount, bpf, clone, setns, seccomp, and ptrace all look promising.

Comment: But in case I run a Linux docker container on Windows the docker container can NOT just use the hosts kernel, simply because Windows has different syscalls then Linux does, or is that a misconception?

Comment: You don't run Linux containers on a Windows host. Instead, you run a Linux VM on Windows, and that VM runs containers. So the question becomes how important is the security of the VM, particularly since it has quite a bit of access granted back into the Windows filesystem.