# NodeJS + Alpine + Puppeteer : Unable to launch browser without --no-sandbox

Tags: node.js, docker, puppeteer, chromium, alpine-linux

We are trying to run some tasks using puppeteer on Alpine Docker + NodeJS. We used to get below error:

```
Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /usr/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-901912/chrome-linux/chrome ENOENT
```

Here is the updated Docker Image with a non root user.

```
FROM alpine
WORKDIR /project
RUN apk add npm
RUN apk add chromium
RUN npm i puppeteer
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true \
    PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
 
RUN adduser pptruser --disabled-password && adduser -S -g pptruser wheel \
     && mkdir -p /home/pptruser/Downloads /app \
     && chown -R pptruser:wheel /home/pptruser \
     && chown -R pptruser:wheel /app \
     && chown -R pptruser:wheel /project
     
 
USER pptruser
```

Now I get the error when I try to launch the docker container using chrome.json seccomp profile:

```
Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted
```

I considered trying with custom seccomp profile as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345581/node-js-puppeteer-on-docker-no-usable-sandbox).

Is there a better way? like having some runtime variables to tell chrome to run in non-sandbox mode  other than using launch args in puppeteer code?