# Securely run puppeteer docker image with Google Chrome when accessing only local files (for PDF generation)

Tags: docker, google-chrome, security, browser, puppeteer

From https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/tree/main/docker#readme

> ### Running the image
>
> ````bash
> puppeteer-chrome puppeteer-chrome-linux node -e "`cat test.js`" ```
>
> `--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN` capability is needed to enable Chromium sandbox
> that makes the browser more secure. Alternatively, it should be
> possible to start the browser binary with the `--no-sandbox` flag.
> ````

However [Why is granting the SYS_ADMIN privilege for a Docker container "bad"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58924511/why-is-granting-the-sys-admin-privilege-for-a-docker-container-bad) answers:

> This is basically [gives] root access to the host.

1. Is there a way to run that image securely without giving docker --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN ?

As far as I understand, that is required for making SandBox, maybe there is other way, or

2. If it is guaranteed, that locally generated files are passed to Chrome, will it be secure to disable SandBox (particular case question) ?

Frankly, it is laugh, that to make SandBox for safer web browsing, the used docker image is given root access, so a browser application with all possible browser-side security risks is now granted elevated permissions. I am sure browser app must be give the least access possible (for browsing Internet/html files).