# How to run chrome securely in docker?

Tags: docker, google-chrome, security

Or, perhaps this boils down to: How do I get or create a working `seccomp` profile for `google-chrome`?

I'd like to create a docker image where I launch Google chrome and browse sites I *do not trust* and do this as safely as possible. There are multiple alternatives. Could you help me  choose the safest among them?

If we try to run chrome naively in docker, we'll get this error:

```bash
$ google-chrome
Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted
[152:152:0804/063753.226725:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(201)] Check failed: . : Operation not permitted (1)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

So we either need to disable the sandbox or allow it to run. The [README.md](https://github.com/Zenika/alpine-chrome/blob/master/README.md) for [Zenika/alpine-chrome](https://github.com/Zenika/alpine-chrome) points out that there are these ways to run chrome under docker:

### With `--no-sandbox`

Run `google-chrome --no-sandbox ...`. I've seen multiple warnings (e.g. [1](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#no-sandbox), [2](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/puppeteer/troubleshooting/#setting-up-chrome-linux-sandbox)),  that I should trust the visited sites (I don't). Apparently here I'm disabling much of chrome security, so I'm effectively trusting docker 100% for safety. Not great. There is even an entire site dedicated to why `--no-sandbox` is a bad idea: https://no-sandbox.io/.

When we run chrome with `--no-sandbox` it also displays this ominous warning upon startup:

> You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --no sandbox. Stability and security will suffer.

[kasmweb/chrome](https://hub.docker.com/r/kasmweb/chrome) (and many others) [use](https://github.com/kasmtech/workspaces-images/blob/0597901db6b9259007dd381343895805e3223c4e/src/ubuntu/install/chrome/install_chrome.sh#L4C42-L4C42) this approach and even sets up `"CommandLineFlagSecurityWarningsEnabled": false` in [`default_managed_policy.json`](https://github.com/kasmtech/workspaces-images/blob/0597901db6b9259007dd381343895805e3223c4e/src/ubuntu/install/chrome/install_chrome.sh#L103C35-L103C35) to avoid the resulting warning message.

### With `SYS_ADMIN` capability

Run `docker run --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN ...` (or worse, using `--privileged`)

This will give docker the necessary permissions to use the sandbox properly. But I'm worried [I'm handing over root to the container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58924714/345716), so here I'll trust the browser sandbox 100% with the entire host, which isn't great.

[puppeteer/puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/tree/main/docker) suggests using this approach.

### "The best": with `seccomp`

[Zenika/alpine-chrome](https://github.com/Zenika/alpine-chrome) suggests using Jessie Frazelle's [`chrome.json`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jfrazelle/dotfiles/master/etc/docker/seccomp/chrome.json) seccomp profile for Chrome and calls it:

> This is The most secure way to run this Headless Chrome docker image.

Launch the container using: `docker run --security-opt seccomp=$(pwd)/chrome.json  ...`. However, when I try this, I get the following error, perhaps because I'm not running headless:

```bash
$ google-chrome
[90:90:0803/004311.319570:FATAL:spawn_subprocess.cc(221)] posix_spawn: Operation not permitted (1)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

I've tried adding `spawn` and `posix_spawn` to Jessie Frazelle's [`chrome.json`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jfrazelle/dotfiles/master/etc/docker/seccomp/chrome.json) (following the pattern in the file) but couldn't get rid of this error. Is this `seccomp` approach really the safest? And if so, how do I modify the `chrome.json` file to make it work?

### Use another browser

Just use firefox and be done with it. But I'd *actually* like to use chrome.

Comment: What did you eventually decide?

Comment: I'm using --no-sandbox for now.

Comment: I am running **chromium** via playwright. It works in a container as non-root user with the seccomp profile. I am using headless, but there is also a headful option (but one must install the x dependencies). You might want to have a look at how they do that in their official Dockerfile.